# Will an international wire transfer to France still work with the wrong bank address?

Tags: banking, money-transfer, international-transfer, wire-transfer

A few days ago I sent a wire transfer from Canada to France. All of the info (wire recipient's financial institution name, bank code, account number/IBAN, wire recipient's name, beneficiary name) is correct except the bank address. Will this result in my money being lost?

Answer (score 1):

If the bank is not an unknown little bank, the address is probably not even looked at - the big players know each other, and recognize their SWIFT/BIC codes right away.

Either way, your money is *not* gone, but worst case will get stuck, and either get automatically reversed to the sender, or after he asks for it. It might take some days, and your fees might be lost, but you get the money back.